# 2 level nested list imported form csv file

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a csv file in the following format (part of the file -  i use another data for another data set informations):

```
idA idB idC idD
1   A   10  x
1   A   10  x
1   A   10  x
1   A   100 xx
1   B   10  x
1   B   100 x
1   B   1000    x
1   C   10  x
1   C   100 x
1   C   1000    xx
1   C   1000    x
2   A   10  x
2   A   10  x
2   A   100 xx
2   A   100 x
2   B   10  x
2   B   100 xx
2   B   100 x
2   B   1000    x
3   C   10  xx
3   C   100 x
3   C   1000    x
3   C   100 x
3   A   10  x
3   A   100 x
3   A   1000    x
```

I need to build a nested list in the following format (to be able to print it wit correct logic)

```
 idA
   idB
    idC
```

In my first attempt, this is what I did:

```
     import pandas as pd 
        import numpy as np
        
        
        df= pd.read_csv("test.csv", delimiter=";", encoding="ISO-8859-1")
        
        list1=list()
        
        ia=0
        ib=0
        
        for j in np.unique(df["idA"]):
            tmp=df[df["idA"]==j]
            
            list1.append(j)
            
            for k in np.unique(tmp["idB"]):
                tmp2=tmp[tmp["idB"]==k][["idC","idD"]]
                list1[ia].append(tmp2)
                
                for l in np.unique(tmp2["idC"]):
                    tmp3=tmp2[tmp2["idC"]==l][["idD"]]
                    
                    list1[ia][ib].append(tmp2)
                ib+= 1
            ia+= 1
        
        print(list1)
```

I get error:

AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'append'

Any tips?

Maybe more details:
I need to get access to single elements from sublist. I have three lists with the common key. For example list are the same but in real they are not. To get informations about subelements i use code now like that:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

df= pd.read_csv("test.csv", delimiter=";", encoding="ISO-8859-1")

list1=list()
list2=list()
list3=list()

for j in np.unique(df["idA"]):

    tmp=df[df["idA"]==j][["idA","idB","idC","idD"]]
    list1.append(tmp)
    
    tmp=df[df["idA"]==j][["idA","idB","idC","idD"]]
    list2.append(tmp)
    
    tmp=df[df["idA"]==j][["idA","idB","idC","idD"]]
    list3.append(tmp)
    


for x, y, z in zip(list1, list2, list3):
    
    for row_index, row in x.iterrows():
        print('')
        #print(row['idA'])

    for row_index, row in y.iterrows():
        print('')
        #print(row['idB'])
        
    t_vk21='xx'
    t_vk31='xx'
    t_vk32='xx'
    t_vk41='xx'
    

    for row_index, row in z.iterrows():
       
        
        t_vk2=row["idB"]
        if t_vk21 != t_vk2:
            t_vk21=t_vk2
            print(t_vk2)
            
        t_vk3=row["idC"]
             
        if t_vk31 != t_vk3:
            t_vk31=t_vk3
            print(t_vk3)   
        
        print(row['idD'])
```

I wanted to create multi list structure to get better access. The expected result is:

```
A
10
x
x
x
100
xx
B
10
x
100
x
1000
x
C
10
x
100
x
1000
xx
x


A
10
x
x
100
xx
x
B
10
x
100
xx
x
1000
x



C
10
xx
100
x
1000
x
100
x
A
10
x
100
x
1000
x
```

Comment: list1[ia][ib].append(tmp2), here list1[ia][ib] gives an integer value... I think you need either list1[ia].append(tmp2) or list1[ia][ib]=tmp2

Comment: list1[ia].append(tmp2) is already not working. 
when i make list1[ia]=tmp2  then print(list1[0]) gives    
 idA idB   idC idD
7     1   C    10   x
8     1   C   100   x
9     1   C  1000  xx
10    1   C  1000   x 
for list1[ia][ib]=tmp3 i get error:
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 4, placement implies 1

Comment: can you add your expected output?